# Can not create folder name up to 400 characters at root level by using OneDrive for Business Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

According to this [website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-onedrive-for-business-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa) , I can create a folder with path length 400 characters.

But I could only create 339 characters folder name at root level. And I find out different account have different length constraint. Why can't I create a folder with 400 characters at root level?

Comment: Does the following apply-->https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/3125202/restrictions-and-limitations-when-you-sync-files-and-folders? "The limit may be less than 400 characters in some scenarios, especially if you have a very long URL path for the library."

Comment: In my experiment, I find the path is not just folder name. Real path starts with /personal/{account_name}_{group_name}_onmicrosoft_com/Documents. The length of prefix path is 61 characters. The sum of prefix path length(61) and max folder path length(339) is just 400. So maybe it is the reason why different account have different limitation. BTW, I find prefix path by webUrl field in drive resources at this website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/drive

Answer (score 0):

From the same [documentation you referenced](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-onedrive-for-business-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa):

> The *entire path*, including the file name, must contain fewer than 400 characters for OneDrive, OneDrive for Business and SharePoint Online. If you exceed that limit, you'll receive an error message. SharePoint Server versions only support up to 260 characters for file and path lengths.